# Addition and intersection of subspaces

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces

Describe the sum $V + W$ and intersection $V \cap W$ of subspaces of $\Bbb{R}^3$ where $V = \{(a + b, a − b, a): a, b \in \Bbb{R}\}$ and $W = \{(−a, 4a, 3a): a \in \Bbb{R}\}$.

Need some direction in how to start this problem as my notes on this topic make no sense to me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

***Hint:*** $V=span\{v_1= (1,1,1),v_2=(1,-1,0) \}$

and

$W=span\{w=(-1,4,3)\}$

(because $(a+b,a-b,a)=a(1,1,1)+b(1,-1,0)$ and $(-a,4a,3a)=a(-1,4,3)$)

Now, try to conclude if $\{v_1,v_2,w\}$ is linearly independent or anything.

Comment: Do i need to include anything else after i have proved that the vectors are linearly independent?

Comment: If ${v_1,v_2,w} is linearly independent, then you can say that $V+W=\Bbb{R}^3$ and $V\cap W={0}$ (do you know why?)

Comment: no I do not know why

Comment: Given three linearly independent vectors $u,v,w \in \Bbb{R}^3$, we know that $\{u,v,w\}$ is a basis to $\Bbb{R}^3$. What can you conclude?

Comment: Because $\{v_1,v_2,w\}$ is a linearly independent set, with three elements, the dimension of its span should be three as well, now, we would have a subspace of $\mathbb{R}^3$ with dimension 3, so the span of $\{v_1,v_2,w\}$, which equals $V+W$, should be $\mathbb{R}^3$ itself. Regarding $V\cap W$, think about its dimension, as we know, dim$(V+W)$=dim$V$+dim$W$-dim$(W\cap V)$, from which it follows that dim$(V\cap W)$=$0$, so $V\cap W$ should be the empty set

Comment: @Arthur Nice! But I think you meant $V\cap W$ should be $\{0\}$.

Comment: Indeed @rdias, thanks!